# How to get boolean value from selectedrow in gridview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do i get a boolean value from a selected gridview row in ASP.NET,
this is what i do to get normal strings from gridview and it works

```
string name = GridViewSokEvent.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text;
```

Altough when i try the same with boolean it wont work, if anyone know how this can be done or have any hints, please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a gridview boolean, they will generate a checkbox for you which you can get your bool value from, something like this should work:

```
 CheckBox c = (CheckBox)GridViewSokEvent.SelectedRow.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if(c.Checked == true)
            {
                 //do something
            }
            else if(c.Checked == false)
            {
                 //do something 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Boolean check = Convert.ToBoolean(GridViewSokEvent.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text));
```

Don't forget exception handling.

UPD. If you do get an exception

Most likely your cell contains: DBNull or null, or an empty string "", neither or which constitute Boolean True or False, or 0 or 1. So you need an if statement where you will check that your cell contains a String that is  "True" or "False" or "0" or "1". As far as I remember Convert.ToBoolean() is not intelligent enough to handle anything else.

```
Boolean check = False;  //Have to initialize outside the if  
string message = GridViewSokEvent.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text;
    if (message == "True" || message == "False" || message == "0" || message == "1")
    {
         check = Convert.ToBoolean(message);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks i tried this and get the error: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code How am i supposed to deal with it? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but maybe this is a good solution for others:

```
Boolean check = GridViewSokEvent.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Value is DBNull ? false:(bool)GridViewSokEvent.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Value;
```